# req.session passport properties do not save

Tags: node.js, dropbox, passport.js

I am able to save a session just fine using passport when a user logs in through facebook. However, I am having trouble once I attempt to attach anything else to the req.session object. I am attempting to attach the dropbox module to req.session so that the user can make dropbox api calls throughout their session.

First, after the oAuth process, I attach the (working) dropbox module like so:

```
exports.createDBoxClient = function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.dropbox = DBoxApp.client(req.dbox_access_token);
  next();
};
```

Second, a user later uploads a file, like so:

```
exports.upload = function(req,res,next){
  req.session.dropbox.put('/'+req.files.file.originalname,req.fileStream,function(status, data){
    next();
  })
};
```

At this point, however, req.session.dropbox is an empty object. Any hints for how to save a user's dropbox functionality after they go through they login to their dropbox account through my site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just save the access token and instantiate a new `DBoxApp.client` object with it when needed?

E.g.

```
exports.saveDropboxToken = function (req, res, next) {
  req.session.dropboxAccessToken = req.dbox_access_token;
  next();
};

exports.upload = function (req,res,next){
    var client = DBoxApp.client(req.session.dropboxAccessToken);
    client.put('/' + req.files.file.originalname,
               req.fileStream,
               function (status, data) {
                   next();
               });
};
```